# Custom Snackbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, snackbar

I want to create a Snackbar in flutter. I want it to have borders on all 4 corners and have a border width with a different color only at bottom side.

Snackbar required :

[image]

I couldn't find a way to add both the properties together.

Can someone suggest a way to do it without using external flutter libraries or a Container inside content parameter of the snackbar widget?

I am able to create only one of the required properties separately.

1. I am able to apply border width at bottom with color.

   ```
              var snackBar = SnackBar(
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
              shape: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green
                      width: 4,
              content: Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                    child:
                        Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Toast message",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
   ```

SnackBar with bottom border width :

[image]

2. I am able to apply corner radius at all 4 corners.

   ```
          var snackBar = SnackBar(
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: 8,
          ),
          content: Flex(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                child:
                   Icon(Icons.add)
              ),
            Text(
               "Toast message",       
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
   ```

Snackbar with border radius:

[image]

I want to apply both properties together but I am unable to it.

Comment: Can you please add minimal code of what did you tried? Also add image of expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget customSnackbar({
  required String message,
  Color backgroundColor = Colors.black,
  Color borderColor = Colors.red,
  double borderWidth = 4.0,
  double cornerRadius = 12.0,
}) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cornerRadius),
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 12.0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 10),
          left: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          right: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        message,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

To use this snackbar just add customSnackbar widget to snackbar

```
const snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: customSnackbar(message: 'Yay! A SnackBar!'),
);
```

And to display the snackbar use scaffold key

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Can you share how I can use this custom widget?

Comment: @AnanyaPathak please check answer I have updated

Comment: Hmm....I did similar to how you have suggested earlier but using a container. It doesn't look like the way we want it to. We have to add backgroundColor as transparent and elevation to the snackbar, still I wouldn't get the required width. So I have to add width to the custom widget (which I don't want to). Tried your code too and had to add bgColor with elevation and the width thing mentioned above in the snackBar var.

Comment: Thank you for the effort @ShubhamNarkhede! I found a way to implement it. :)